# Why does ln -sf silently fail?

Tags: symlink, ln

`ln -sf source_file target_file` succeeds even when source_file does not exist.

`ln -f source_file target_file` on the other hand fail, as expected.

How can it be tuned to give error on the first case *without* first testing for the file existence explicitly (i.e. not `[[ -e source_file ]] && ln -sf source_file target_file`)

Comment: I could not duplicate this behavior. For me using `-s` alone with a non-existent source creates a broken symlink silently. `ln -f` without `-s` must of course fail because you're asking it to increase the ref count on a non-existent inode.

Comment: Can you show exacly what "two different commands" you ran and what error they produced?  I suspect that you are mixing hard- and symlinks

Comment: @sendmoreinfo You are right, I was expecting broken symlinks creation to fail just as hard links would but it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `ln` man page:

> When creating hard links, each TARGET must exist.

No mention of symlinks there; in fact, this statement seems to imply that this is not the case for symlinks.

As I said in my comment on your question, when creating a symlink to a non-existent source, a broken link is created:

```
$ ln -sfv blah blabla
'blabla' -> 'blah'
$ file blabla
blabla: broken symbolic link to 'blah'
```

As far as `ln` is concerned, there's no reason to cry error: you asked for a symlink and it obliged. Shy of aliasing `ln`, I don't see a way to do what you want without explicitly checking for the existence of the source file.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I want to achieve -  silent failing is the observed behavior, the expected behavior would be the explicit error given when using either `-f` or `-s` alone. When combined - it fails silently and I'd like to change that.

Comment: @akurster I see. Would you mind adding `-sf` to the very first `ln source_file target_file` in your question, then?

Comment: @akurtser Answer changed.

Comment: My bad, sorry, question changed.